# Can't fix a typo in a question?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I was just reading [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/581546/20363), and noticed that OP started talking about hens:

> However, hen you click on an icon in an Office application,

Trying to do my civic duty, I edited and entered a 'w' in the appropriate place and clicked 'save'.

SF comes up with a message saying:

```
Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?
```

The answer, was otherwise well worded and not needed of change... and definitely didn't need some other random 5 letters that would just be spam...

Is this limit really necessary... or is there a way to alert mod's that have the ability to change it?

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the typo. The limit is deemed necessary by the powers that be. There is plenty of discussion about it on [m.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=six%20character) and even some here on [m.sf](https://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=6%20character). I don't believe the limit is likely to change.